# Call to NotifyProportyChanged when adding items to List doesn't work, why?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to understand why calling the function (code below...) of `NotifyProportyChanged` from `AddNoteToList` to update the view whenever item added to list isn't working.

It works great when I'm doing an assignment on the list, but if I'm trying to add items and then call manually the `NotifyProportyChanged` it doesn't.

I know I should use `ObservableCollection` to solve the problem, but I would like to know **why** this implementation I wrote is not doing the job.

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model.MainWindowModel Model { get; set; }

    public List<DataProtocol.Note> _notesListVM;
    public List<DataProtocol.Note> NotesListVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _notesListVM;
        }
        set
        {
            _notesListVM = value;
            NotifyProportyChanged("NotesListVM");
        }
    }



    //dp:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyProportyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    //Command: 
    public RelayCommand AddNoteCommand { get; set; }
    public void AddNoteToList(object parm)
    {
        string value = parm.ToString();
        NotesListVM.Add(new DataProtocol.Note(value));
        NotifyProportyChanged("NotesListVM");

    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        Model = new PL.Model.MainWindowModel();
        NotesListVM = Model.NotesList;
        AddNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(AddNoteToList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the _instance_ of the list did not change. `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifiyCollectionChanged` which is used by the view to wait for updates of the list's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are raising `PropertyChanged`, the object instance `NotesListVM` hasn't actually changed, only its content has. WPF is optimized enough to realize this and do nothing.

If you really wanted to do it your way, you'd need create and assign a new list each time.

As you say, use `ObservableCollection` instead, which will fire `CollectionChanged`.

Comment: "you'd need create and assign a new list each time". not really. set property to `null` and re-assign previous list will work as well. the downside is that ItemsControl will have to re-create many visual items instead of one which was added

Answer (score 0):

ItemsControl.ItemsSource is a dependency property, and will only register a change when you actually set the value to a different collection instance - sending a PropertyChanged event isn't sufficient.

As you noted, using an ObservableCollection is the correct way to have your bound U.I. controls detect that items have been added / removed from your list of items.